# Add .svg into a plot in bokeh

Tags: python, svg, plot, jupyter-notebook, bokeh

Is it possibile to import a path that is in .svg format into a plot in bokeh. If someone could give me a north that would be great, because so far my research did not encounter much information about the subject.

Answer (score 0):

No such API exists as of Bokeh 2.3.3 and I'm not aware of any issue regarding it, either (AFAIK you are the first person to ask about it).